# Is is possible to make a cURL request and get the route that is taken (similar to traceroute)

Tags: curl, traceroute

I have a GET request with header params and I want to check which db instance my app is using. Is there a way I could build a cURL request that would tell me where my request is going? I know there is a `traceroute` command which displays all the server hops. But is there something similar to that using a cURL?

Comment: Did you try the `--trace` option? `curl -v -X TRACE http://www.yourserver.com`

Answer (score 23):

For a slightly better formatted output to stdout

```
curl --trace-ascii - <host>
```

Comment: this does not answer the question because I cannot find a route in this output !?! just the TLS hansdshake

Answer (score 10):

You can use --trace option: `--trace FILE    Write a debug trace to FILE`

`curl --trace trace.txt yourdomain.com`

(You cannot use trace and verbose at the same time, trace overrides it)

Comment: I tried this, but the resulting file doesn't seem to display the IP addresses of the machine at each hop of the request.

Comment: this does not answer the question because I cannot find a route in this output !?! just the TLS hansdshake

Answer (score 0):

```
curl -L -v --noproxy '*' --trace-ascii data.txt https://example.com
```

---

`-L` will follow the redirects

`-v` is for verbose

`--noproxy '*'` This flag instructs curl to not use any proxy and connect directly to https://example.com

`--trace-ascii data.txt` : Will store the output in data.txt