# random ssl certification failure

Tags: firefox, python-requests, aws-api-gateway, microsoft-edge, tls1.2

I just setup a custom domain for an AWS API Gateway and set up CNAME entries in Google Domains to redirect to my API Gateway. After maybe 30 minutes of waiting I was able to use Chrome to do a simple GET request to my custom domain that properly forwarded to my API Gateway. I tested in Firefox and it worked fine too.

About 3-4 hours later I came back and tried making the same call using Python requests and it worked the first 3 times then failed.

`SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='ids.references.app', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError("hostname '<my_custom_domain>' doesn't match '*.execute-api.us-east-2.amazonaws.com'")))`

At first I thought this was a requests problem, but then I opened up Firefox and it didn't work as well. I tried Edge and the call worked. Then I went back to Python and it worked for a bit, then stopped working. I went back to Firefox and it no longer worked. Then I tried Edge and it no longer worked. Sprinkled in there I've tried Chrome and it has worked every time since it started working. (this order of events is from memory and may be slightly off).

Is this a known issue with updating DNS entries that you get some randomness when things first start until the DNS changes have fully propagated. How would I go about even tracking where the error is occurring? I think that's the most frustrating thing about this, it all seems like magic and there's no obvious point where you get something like server 1.2.3.4 says that cert_1 doesn't go with cert_2 and then later you see something like server 4.5.6.7 says cert_2 is all good (so it works). Would I need to install curl for Windows ([Is is possible to make a cURL request and get the route that is taken (similar to traceroute)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45178804/is-is-possible-to-make-a-curl-request-and-get-the-route-that-is-taken-similar-t)). Would this even matter though? What if curl was like Chrome, it always worked? Does requests have this functionality (bonus points if someone can show a requests solution)? What about Firefox or Chrome? Or could I use something like wireshark (yikes) that could somehow observe the whole system?

I'm using requests 2.25.1 and Python 3.8.5 on Windows 10 and I believe the latest versions of Edge and Firefox.

Comment: Just discovered https://www.whatsmydns.net Strangely, the first time I ran it it failed in like New York, LA, New Zealand, and Pakistan. I tried again 2 seconds later and now only Pakistan is failing .... Not sure if I'm going to see it fail again. I've hit the button 10-15x now with the same result (sort of fun to watch).

Comment: Right after posting that last comment I got failure in Reston VA, Quebec, Silkeborg, Shenzhen, and Pakistan. WTF?!?!?